permission denied when npm-installing OpenAI realtime API
All I'm trying to do is npm install openai realtime API and I'm getting permission denied.
npm i openai/openai-realtime-api-beta
npm error code 128
npm error An unknown git error occurred
npm error command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/openai/openai-realtime-api-beta.git
npm error git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm error
npm error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm error and the repository exists.


It looks like this is your problem:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
npm is trying to clone the /openai/openai-realtime-api-beta.git repository but cannot connect over SSH because your public key hasn't been registered with GitHub.
GitHub has a walk-through on how to set this up. Once you follow the step-by-step instructions, this should work for you.
